# How to keep c# and ardunio communication in sync?

Tags: c#

I am writing a simple app where an Ardunio sends read data to the C# program using simple serial.write()'s. I send the data from Ardunio with special syntax and the c# program reads and interprets it and eventually graphs the data.

For example, the Ardunio program sends data

```
Serial.write("DATA 1 3 90;");
```

which means: X value and Y value in chart 1 is 3 and 90 respectively. And the c# program reads it using

```
private async void Serialport_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    await serialport.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1024);

    await Task.Run(() => Graph()); // Graph function graphs the data

}
```

In the graph() function, I convert the buffer to a string with Encode.ASCII.GetString(buffer); and interpret the data with the syntax and stuff. But for some reason either the c# program doesn't read it fast enough or the Arduino doesn't send it fast enough and the messages are sometimes interrupted For example the packet I received is:

DATA 2 5 90;DATA 5 90 10;DATA 1 1 <|-------- I cannot get the last Y Value

And the next data module starts with

75;DATA 5 4 60;DATA 14 5 6;DATA

/\

|

+==================== It is here

BTW, all the packets are 32 bytes.

So I either need to get the data line by line but I cannot do that because ardunio sends it too fast

```
 Serial.write("DATA 1 3 90;");
 Serial.write("DATA 2 4 40;");
```

Comes to C# as DATA 1 3 90;DATA 2 4 40; as a whole block. Or I need to get it all at once?

(I prefer getting it line by line)

UPDATE:

When delay(1000); is added between sends. The data is processed correctly. Without the delays, Arduino sends the data too fast, and data clumps and interrupted. How can I make sure that there is no delay in the data yet the data is reliable and without interruption?

UPDATE 2:

When buffer size is increased to 100 * 1024 * 1024 as well as the readCount in ReadAsync method, the read message is much larger still with interruptions tho.

I can give you any extra information.

UPDATE 3:

I ll try to answer the comments;

First of all, I am already doing that and I forgot to mention it. I split the incoming data from the semicolons and interpret them one by one with a foreach loop

Second I am using buffer globally instead of passing it as an argument to graph function

Third I ll try Serial.PrintLine and give you feedback on it

UPDATE 4:

I was able to solve the problem by replacing ReadAsync with Serial.ReadLine() and serial.write with serial.printline(); The solution is suggested by Hans Passant

UPDATE 5:

I still encounter the same problem but differently. The graph function is async so when I write the data so fast I miss some data trying to graph and read other data.

Also because the graph function is async chart control plots the points without order and the graph gets messy.

This can be easily solvable if I add delay(50) between Serial.println()'s

PS. I didn't give the whole code because it is a large block. But I can give it piece by piece if you tell me where you want it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're receiving a stream of data -- the fact that you're using two calls to `Serial.write` is meaningless: you might as well write `Serial.write("DATA 1 3 90;DATA 2 4 40")`. It's entirely expected that you might read the data received so far, while you're still receiving data. You need some logic which looks at the data received so far, and tries to parse from `DATA` to the `;`. If it doesn't find the `;`, it should wait until it's received some more data, then try again.

Comment: One problem is, you are ignoring the return value of ReadAsync(), which is the number of bytes that has actually been read. Now, how do you know whether the data that you've received contains a complete message or not? You can implement a simple parser which looks for `;` and calls Graph() with a single but complete message. Try not to use the `buffer` as a shared variable also.

Comment: Improve the Arduino code a bit so it gets easy to read on the C# side.  Use Serial.println(), now you can use SerialPort.ReadLine().  Guarantees you get the full response, ready to parse.  There is no benefit at all in using ReadAsync()

Comment: @canton7 I added an update

Comment: @OguzOzgul I added an update

Comment: @HansPassant I added an update